# Combine two colums of string data in one with selection rule

Tags: python, pandas

I have to combine two colums of string data in one (in the same DataFrame), also I need some sort of selection rule, I give you an example

```
  import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'nameA':['martin', 'peter', 'john', 'tom', 'bill'], 
                       'nameB':[ np.NaN,np.NaN , 'jhon', 'tomX', 'billX']})
    df

    nameA   nameB
0   martin  NaN
1   peter   NaN
2   john    jhon
3   tom     tomX
4   bill    billX
```

This output is the expected behavior

```
    nameA   nameB   nameAB
0   martin  NaN     martin
1   peter   NaN     peter
2   john    jhon    jhon
3   tom     tomX    tomX
4   bill    billX   bilX
```

the rule should be something like this:

1. if A and B are different write B
2. if B are NaN write A
3. if A and B are NaN write NaN

I have found tips with numbers but no with strings, I think I have to test row by row and get a true o false value and then write the appropriate value

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks all,  I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
In [1972]: df['nameAB'] = df.nameB.combine_first(df.nameA)

In [1973]: df
Out[1973]: 
    nameA  nameB  nameAB
0  martin    NaN  martin
1   peter    NaN   peter
2    john   jhon    jhon
3     tom   tomX    tomX
4    bill  billX   billX
```

Comment: Yes Mayank, I really surprise that there is a method that fulfil my question, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'nameA': ['martin', 'peter', 'john', 'tom', 'bill'],
                   'nameB': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 'jhon', 'tomX', 'billX']})


df['nameAB'] = np.where(pd.isna(df['nameB']), df['nameA'], df['nameB'])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    nameA  nameB  nameAB
0  martin    NaN  martin
1   peter    NaN   peter
2    john   jhon    jhon
3     tom   tomX    tomX
4    bill  billX   billX
```

Given your conditions you only return `nameA` when `nameB` is `nan`.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
df['nameAB'] = df['nameB'].fillna(df['nameA'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    nameA  nameB  nameAB
0  martin    NaN  martin
1   peter    NaN   peter
2    john   jhon    jhon
3     tom   tomX    tomX
4    bill  billX   billX
```